# How can I copy the plain text of equation in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, equations

I made a trend line and its equation in libreoffice calc:

[image: Trend line equation]

Now, I want to copy the equation's plan text, but the copy function copies the equation as an object:

[image: Equation copy]

And then I can only paste it inside liberoffice, but still in a objext-like format, (or in .png format using shift+ctrl+V). If I double click it, it lets me write/delete in it new text, but it does not let me select the equation!

[image: equation weird behavior]

How can I get the plain text of the equation?
I just do not want to have to type all of the equation every time I want to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This trick**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=280232#p280232) has been around for years
*(I'm posting it to say **"Thank you, @acknak!"**)*

[image: Solution]

> Copy the equation in the chart to clipboard.
>
> Start a new OO Draw window: File > New > Drawing
>
> Paste the equation
>
> Select the equation and right-click > Break
>
> Now you can click into the text and copy/paste it as plain text
> anywhere you like.

Comment: Damn @acknak's DP looks as you would expect. Like a boss